# How can I interpret a string as an HTML page without creating the page on the server

Tags: javascript, html, string, vb.net, iframe

I have an aspx page with an IFrame in it.  I need to set a string as the IFrame content and have IFrame (or the client, or the server) interpret and display the string as if it were an actual HTML page.

The string would be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title></title></head><body><div>Some Text Here</div></body></html>
```

I can't write the string to an actual HTML page because I'm afraid if two users happened to hit the same page at the same time, they might get each other's content due to latency, etc...

I don't speak Perl/PHP and I've never used JSON, Ajax, JQuery, or anything fancier than HTML, Javascript, .asp, .aspx, CSS, VB/C#, and XML (willing to learn, but time does not permit right now).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Any help would be gratefully accepted and highly appreciated!

Comment: `...if two users happened to hit the same page at the same time, they might get each other's content...` Okay, that really needs to be explained.  What is the content of the page and how would two people get different content?  This really sounds like an *[XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)*

Comment: My methods create the IFrame HTML content from XML files selected by each user.  If the server creates an HTML file with same name each time, then serves it to the user, isn't it possible that user A's chosen content could be written to the file,  but before the server can serve it because of high latency,, user B makes a selection that is overwritten to the same file and that content is actually served to User A?  Maybe I'm just punch-drunk from coding all day and need sleep...

Comment: "...creates an HTML file with same name each time..." - don't do that. Does it *have* to use an iframe, or might you choose some other way, like displaying the data in the normal flow of the page, if you could?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I DON'T want to do that, which is why I wanted to create a dynamic "pseudo-page" that isn't tied to a filename. To create a new filename each time would be messy.  The IFrame is necessary because the content is different lengths and I like the vertical scrollbar when it's too long, and it is only a "part" of the page like this comment box is (except It's not user input like this).

Comment: @FlipFitchSt4rdust I see you've found a solution, but you might like to know that you can use CSS to set the max-height of an element and use overflow-y: auto to show a vertical scrollbar necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use srcdoc property like below:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").srcdoc = "<p>Some new content inside the iframe!</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Deep!  It works great!  Another addition to HTML5 that I missed.

Comment: Glad It was helpful.